# Unable to install windows 7 UEFI fail

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-7-x64, uefi

I'm trying to install Windows 7 x64 (currently on Windows 8 x64 & got nVidia driver memory leaks, that's why I'm downgrading) but once I enter te UEFI and select my USB device to boot I get a black screen with a white blinking text indicator. And nothing happens it just stays that way until I reboot or unput the USB device.

Thought it could be a USB 3.0 problem but USB 2.0 ports dont work either.
I have done manny OS intalls before never had a problem like this...

System Specs:
core I7-4770k CPU
Z87-G45 MSI motherbord
Corsair PRO series (2x4GB @ 1333Mhz) RAM 
series 830 samsung (128GB) SSD
GTX 770 MSI GPU
HX650 corsair PSU

Maybe someone has a fix for this problem, or I'm missing something stupid..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the option `Fast Boot` enabled in the UEFI. I had to disable this, too on my Dell Laptop to dual boot Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try open source Rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie/). You  will need another Windows machine to build your bootable USB and the operating system ISO. It is simple to use and fast; select mbr, browse to your ISO and start it running. I used Rufus successfully to install Ubuntu 14.14 on a strange little UEFI laptop with Windows 7 (bugged with all sorts of weird and invasive Chinese 'apps') after all other approaches failed.